# In powershell is there a way to display only a set of parameters based on the selected value

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

Below is the code snippet and here I'm finding a way to display only a set of parameters based on the action I choose. 
For example if I choose action as *Create* then it should show only two parameters *Create_param1* & *Create_param2* similarly for action as *Copy* it should show only *Copy_param1* & *Copy_param2*

I'm not sure if it is a possible or not. Please suggest.

```
function test(){
[cmdletbinding()]
param(
    [ValidateSet('Create', 'Copy')]
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]$Action,

        [string]$Create_param1,
        [string]$Create_param2,

        [string]$Copy_param1,
        [string]$Copy_param2

    )
}
```

Comment: i don't know if it was available in ps2 or ps3, but you can use parameter sets to get what you want in ps5+. do a search for `powershell parameter set` to see demos of the idea.

Comment: You can also create `Dynamic Parameters` that are available only under certain conditions e.g. in your example only if the "Create" parameter is specificed. It just depends how much trouble you want to go to

Comment: As @Scepticalist said, dynamic parameter is the answer: https://www.powershellmagazine.com/2014/05/29/dynamic-parameters-in-powershell/